# Samba is not launching ubuntu 18.04

Tags: samba

How to configure samba on Ubuntu 18.04

I installed Samba from Ubuntu Software and its not launching and I also installed gksu after uninstalling samba and reinstalled it

Comment: By using this command Samba is working fine "gksu system-config-samba "

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little light on details but here are some suggestions:

1. Check if Samba is installed:

   ```
   whereis samba
   ```
2. Make a Samba share (Samba needs to know what you want to share!):

   ```
   mkdir /home/<username>/sambashare/
   sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
   ```
3. At the bottom of the file, add the following lines:

   ```
       [sambashare]
       comment = Samba on Ubuntu
       path = /home/username/sambashare
       read only = no
       browsable = yes
   ```
4. Finally, restart Samba so that it loads your new configuration:

   ```
   sudo service smbd restart
   ```
5. Now you need to create a Samba user (*not* one that already exists in your system):

   ```
   sudo smbpasswd -a username
   ```
6. Samba should now be running. To connect to the Samba share from another computer:

   - Under Mac OS X or Linux: Open a file browser, click on connect to server and in the dialogue box, enter `smb://ip-address/sambashare` (replacing `ip-address` and `sambashare` with your values.)
   - On Windows, open File Explorer and in the path at the top of the window enter `\\ip-address\sambashare`

Hopefully, you're sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that by "Samba" you mean system-config-samba and not the samba package.

Since you already installed gksu somehow and assuming it works the only part remaining is to add the magic file. This will create an empty file that system-config-samba requires to run:

```
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

If that doesn't work you might consider this: [While launching samba I get an Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064972/while-launching-samba-i-get-an-error)

*Side Note: You should consider learning how to create your own shares directly as RichardC outlines above since it's likely this application will eventually be removed from the repository: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-samba/+bug/1740419*